# Question displaying with a line break at the beginning where there should be none

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The question [Where is the Mysterious Trader from The Witcher 2 DLC 1?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22975/where-is-the-mysterious-trader-from-the-witcher-2-dlc-1) has the following content:

```
Where is the Mysterious Trader from The Witcher 2 DLC 1? More specifically, the one from Act 3.
```

You'll note the lack of blank line at the beginning.  However, this is how it displays:

[image: screenshot]

My red line is approximately where the top of the text *should* be.  The `post-text` <div> is inside another <div> with `style="display: block; "`.  This outer div normally has no style attribute, at least not on the normally-behaving questions I just checked.

I think this is a bug, but if not, why is this question special?  Editing the question has no effect (at least the minor edit Jeff just made anyways).  I also tried posting the same text in a question elsewhere and the <div> remained styleless.

In case it matters, this has occurred on various up-to-date Chrome versions, plus IE8 and Firefox 6.0, on Windows XP.

**Edit:** As Tim found below, it's because the question is so short.  His workarounds would probably be preferable to the current behavior, which I still view as a bug.

Comment: mysterious! I'll check with Jin.

Comment: The problem is simply that the question is *so* short that the controls on the left take up more vertical space than everything on the right. Adding a `vertical-align:top;` to `#question .postcell`, or a `min-height:` to `#question .post-text` will fix it.

Comment: @Tim Hmm, it doesn't do that on Android. Editing it into 3 lines worked got rid of the problem though.

Comment: Yeah, Android has `vertical-align:baseline` on the post cell, which also seems to work. Luckily, Jin is on the case! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Great, thanks for the fast response.

Comment: They better be giving you extra bacon for that incredibly speedy fix.

Comment: @Tim as you suspected, .postcell {vertical-align:top } fixed the problem. I've added it to shared LESS so it will affect all SE2.0 sites.